# Homogenous system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Let the following homogenous system of differential equation:
>
> $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x'=ax+by\\y'=cx+dy\end{array}\right.$$

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ is not diagonalizable and has complex roots conjugate: $\alpha\pm i\beta$

How do I arrive at the fundamental Matrix of solutions:

$$e^{\alpha t}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\beta t&\sin\beta t\\\sin\beta t&\cos\beta t\end{pmatrix}$$

Why this particular matrix?

Comment: You need variable $t$ also in the matrix ($\beta$ should be $\beta t$)

Comment: @JeanMarie Right, I'll edit it right away!

Comment: You can find the answer in any textbook about systems of differential equations.

Comment: You need to apply your matrix to a vector of initial conditions. See the following MIT document :  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf

Comment: I believe that the answer you found is actually for the case where $A$ *is* diagonalizable. If the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ is *not* diagonalizable then it cannot have two distinct eigenvalues (I assume your "roots" are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, i. e. eigenvalues of the matrix?).

Comment: @Christoph ofcourse they are the eigenvalues of the matrix,

Comment: I see, thanks! I believe there must also be a minus sign somewhere in your fundamental matrix, can you please check again with your source?

Comment: Agreed with @Christoph—you should end up with a rotation times an exponential, so there’s a missing minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Pretend for the moment that you’re working with complex matrices. The coefficient matrix has two distinct eigenvalues and you can find corresponding *complex* eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ using the usual method, but working in the complex domain. Plunging ahead, you then have $$e^{tA} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}e^{(\alpha+i\beta)t}&0\\0&e^{(\alpha-i\beta)t}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$ Multiply this out and simplify using the identities $$\cos\theta = \frac12\left(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}\right) \\ \sin\theta = \frac1{2i}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right).$$